# What do you call a word that's been used unusually (not according to definition)?

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech

For example, when you say:

> They smelt music

or

> He forged a meaning out of it

According to dictionary definitions, the word choices in the above sentences might not fit. The usage is more figurative. Is there a word that describes this?

Comment: A *solecism*? Though those are usually more credible and forgivable than the complete misuse which characterizes your example.

Answer (score 12):

That is a ***[figurative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figurative)*** usage of terms:

> - of words, language, etc. : used with a meaning that is different from the basic meaning and that expresses an idea in an interesting way by using language that usually describes something else : not literal

(M-W)

Also ***[metaphoric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/metaphoric):***

> - A figure of speech in which a word or phrase that ordinarily designates one thing is used to designate another, thus making an implicit comparison, as in "a sea of troubles" or "All the world's a stage" (Shakespeare).

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks for the response. I thought there might be something more specific than figurative usage but I guess that's all it is.

Answer (score 7):

Try [catachresis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catachresis) -

> An application of a term to something which it does not properly denote.

Also, there is [heterophemy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heterophemy) -

> The use of some other word or phrase in place of the one that was meant.

Comment: I think this refers to a different issue.

Comment: @Josh61 how about catachresis? Is that at least an improvement? :)

Answer (score 5):

> *They smelt music*

This is a [synaesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaesthesia_(rhetorical_device)).

> a rhetorical device or figure of speech where one sense is described in terms of another

Comment: Do you think it's a upward or downward movement in regards to Panchronistic tendencies?

Comment: Term is likely too specific since it entirely misses the mark on the second example.

Comment: Great answer. It also has a medical significance. It describes a strangely beautiful yet scary condition. I didn't know this word had two definitions or I'd have included it too. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia

Comment: 56451301303, I think as you smell a sound that would be downwards.@Myles, the other example had already been posted by @vickyace. No need to repeat.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [***malapropism***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropism) is at least close enough to be worth mention:

> the usually unintentionally humorous misuse or distortion of a word or phrase

Answer (score 1):

Such a usage might be considered (especially in retrospect)
to be a [***neologism***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neologism):

> a new word or expression or a new meaning of a word

This might be particularly applicable to your "forged" example.